# Can I mark my name on siddurs and tallis

Tags: halacha

As per title can I mark my name on my tallis and my siddurs to deter people from stealing them again?

Comment: Why not? (15151515)

Comment: And a belated [welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Frank, thanks for this first question and  hope to see you around!

Comment: Just don't make a large coloration on the corners of the tallis

Comment: As a friend of old books, I find it extremely fascinating, when people write their names and anniversaries in their books. Many cases it's the only way for your descendants to know something about you 100 years later. Artscroll Chumash has even a printed section for that. I also have my great grandmother's and grandfather's message from the war, it's priceless...

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't want to desecrate them, at least when I buy new ones to replace the stolen ones.